# (Solidity Browser) VM Exception: invalid opcode

Tags: solidity, remix, invalid-opcode

I access the solidity browser from the following URL.

https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/

There are one basic sample code and one "Ballot" sample code when the page is opened by default. I have compiled the original code (no change on default code) by pressing "Compile" button in "Settings" page.

And I press the "Create" button in "Contract" page. However, only "VM Exception: invalid opcode" is shown even I tried in Google Chrome and IE.

Would anyone advise in this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had set a value in the "value input" before creating the contract.

put 0 and retry to create the contract. the ballot example works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right and the problem is solved.